# The connection pool named: |apex|| is not correctly configured, due to the following error(s): ORA-28001: the password has expired in apex

Tags: localhost, oracle-apex, local

How to solve this type of errors in apex local host 'The connection pool named: |apex|| is not correctly configured, due to the following error(s): ORA-28001: the password has expired ' What is the solution for fix this.

Comment: You will need to reset the password for that connection pool in the database and in APEX. This will require the assistance of the DBA to fix. In the future, be prepared to reset the password *before* it expires, or have the DBA configure it *not* to expire automatically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.